# macro for repeated explicit instantiation

Tags: c++, c++14

Given a set of template functions and classes,

```cpp
template <int dim>
class A;

template <int dim>
void F();
```

is it possible to define a macro `MULTIDIM` that would do explicit instantiation of these templates for multiple values of parameter `dim` (e.g. `dim=1` and `dim=2`)?

For example,

```cpp
MULTIDIM(
template class A<DIM>;
template void F<DIM>();
)
```

is supposed to instantiate the same entities as

```cpp
template class A<1>;
template void F<1>();

template class A<2>;
template void F<2>();
```

One way to define it could be something like

```cpp
#define MULTIDIM(x) \
  constexpr int DIM = 1; x  \
  constexpr int DIM = 2; x
```

but obviously this is not valid since both definitions of `DIM` are
in the same scope.

Comment: Lookup "X macro".

Comment: Although since this is C++, there's also something like [c++ - Instantiate function for all combinations of template params, choose instantation at run time - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562342/instantiate-function-for-all-combinations-of-template-params-choose-instantatio) or [c++ - How can I concisely write a lot of explicit function template instantiations? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338955/how-can-i-concisely-write-a-lot-of-explicit-function-template-instantiations) -- whether it's a better way is up to you.

Comment: thanks, X macro will work